# Codeigniter website not working on live server page not found

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have uploaded my website on 000webhost server in vegshop folder, my link is "http://sp16bcs034.000webhostapp.com/vegshop/", however there is error 404 page not found

and my .htaccess file code is:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 
!^(index\.php|resources|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I suspect your default controller in config/routes.php may be the culprit.  Make sure it matches the controller you want to use.  This is the most common error when no URI is present.

Comment: $route['default_controller'] = 'products';

Comment: It is working fine in local xampp server

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

Open config.php and do following replaces

```
$config['index_page'] = "index.php"
```

to

```
$config['index_page'] = ""
```

In some cases the default setting for uri_protocol does not work properly. Just replace

```
$config['uri_protocol'] ="AUTO"
```

by

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI"
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Note: .htaccess code vary depending on hosting server. In some hosting server  need to use an extra ? in the last line of above code. The following line will be replaced with last line in applicable case:

// Replace last .htaccess line with this line

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: how to know the last line for my server

Comment: can you please check it if I share with you hosting details?

Answer (score 0):

Try this htaccess file, you have uploaded code in the subfolder.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ /vegshop/index.php [L] 
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /vegshop/index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Or sometimes time you have to replace the last line in above code with this as per server

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /vegshop/index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

### Place below .htaccess file in vegshop folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /vegshop
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<ifmodule !mod_rewrite.c>
  ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</ifmodule>
```

### In application/config/config.php set as below

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://sp16bcs034.000webhostapp.com/vegshop/';
```

Comment: I have made this config in route file: $route['default_controller'] = 'products';